# Sorting dropdown in Angular without case sensitive

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I was having problem when trying to sort the dropdown values in Angular Typescript. I am trying to sort by staffName:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <strong><label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="staff.staffReportingOfficer" for="field_staffReportingOfficer">Staff Reporting Officer</label></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control" id="field_staffReportingOfficer" name="staffReportingOfficer" [(ngModel)]="staff.staffReportingOfficer" (change)="roDropdownOnChange()">
                    <option [ngValue]='' disabled>Please select an Option</option>
                    <option [ngValue]="reportingOfficerOption.id === staff.reportingOfficer?.id ? staff.reportingOfficer.staffName : reportingOfficerOption.staffName" *ngFor="let reportingOfficerOption of reportingOfficers | orderBy: 'staffName'">{{reportingOfficerOption.staffName}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My staffs array contains data like A, B, C, D, E, aaaa. Then it is showing the exact same sequence as above.

My desired output will be like A, aaaa, B, C, D, E. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think Angular has an OrderBy pipe anymore. You will need to manually sort your array

Comment: Check this example, I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfw5ia?file=app/table-sorting-example.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular no longer has the OrderBy pipe. You may refer to [this](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#built-in-pipes) for more details.

You will need to manually sort your `reportingOfficers` array. It seems it is an array of objects?

To perform a case insensitve sort, we will need to supply a custom sorting function by converting `staffName` values to lower case.

```
reportingOfficers.sort((a, b) => a['staffName'].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b['staffName'].toLowerCase()));
console.log(reportingOfficers);
```

This is how it is done with vanilla JavaScript/TypeScript (without relying on additional libraries such as Lodash).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lodash` for this

```js
var arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b']

console.log(_.sortBy(arr, function (val) {
 return val.toLowerCase();
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```